# UITableView cell square instead of round

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UICollectionView, when i tap collection cell UITableView appear. I want
that UITableViewCell's image be round, and when i first load this table all images are round, when i select in and move inside detail controller, then switch back they are still round. But, when i enter UITableView (down from UICollectionView), then press "Back" button to see UICollectionView again, then press UICollectionView cells, it shows me UITableView with visible "square (default) image" cell. Why i say visible? Well, when i scroll down, new cells are round again as they should be. Why this nasty bug appear? There is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    myCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *labelText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    labelText.text = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[myCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"imageFirst"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noPhoto.png" ]completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){

        UIImage *resizedImage = [image resizedImageWithBounds:CGSizeMake(66, 66)];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.imageView.image = resizedImage;
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.bounds.size.width /2.0f;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 82, 0, 0);
    }];
    self.stringToPass    = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"description"];

    return cell;
}
```

Why images square when user get back to first view and then again switch to UITableView?

Comment: Replace `cell.imageView.clipsToBounds` with `cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds`.

Comment: Its not work and even warn me "yellow" error ..

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Im sorry, i was wrong. There is no yellow error, but there is the same "bug". First it rounded, when i switch to main screen and go again to tableView it square.

Comment: Put the layer rounding code outside the block you submit to SDWebImage with the corner radius being 33, since you know what the dimensions of the images are going to be.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, duci9y it actually work! Thank you a lot! Please, answer to this post, so i can check this as "answer for my question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the images you fetch resized to definite dimensions of 66x66, you can set the `cornerRadius` irrespective of the image being set.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    …
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 33.0;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    …
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is related with this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Try that for setting the image inside the cell (are you using SDWebImage)?

```
// Set the corner radius and clip to bounds before setting the image
[cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imageView.frame.size.width/2];
cell.imageView.clipToBounds = YES;
// I'm using SDWebImage
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"imageFirst"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noPhoto.png"]];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It does make it round, but bug isn't vanished.. :(

Comment: If makes it round, what is the bug?

Comment: When i switch back to main screen, then tap UICollectionView to see second View controller that contain UITableView, this time images are squared.